# How do I split a unicode string on code points in python? (eg. \u00B7 or \u2022)?

Tags: python, unicode, split, points, codepoint

I tried **everything** I could think of...

```
1. unicode_obj.split('\u2022')
2. re.split(r'\u2022', unicode_object)
3. re.split(r'(?iu)\u2022', unicode_object)
```

Nothing worked

The problem is that I want to split on special characters.

```
example string : u'<special char like middot:\u00b7 or bullet:\u2022> sdfhsdf <repeat special char> sdfjhdgndujhfsgkljng <repeat special char> ... etc'
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you split using `u'\u2022'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider:

```
>>> print '\u2022'
\u2022
>>> print len('\u2022')
6
>>> import unicodedata
>>> map(unicodedata.name, '\u2022'.decode('ascii'))
['REVERSE SOLIDUS', 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U', 'DIGIT TWO', 'DIGIT ZERO', 'DIGIT TWO', 'DIGIT TWO']
>>>
```

vs:

```
>>> print u'\u2022'
•
>>> print len(u'\u2022')
1
>>> map(unicodedata.name, u'\u2022')
['BULLET']
>>>
```

This should make the difference between `text.split('\u2022')` and `text.split(u'\u2022')` clear.

Comment: Thank you for having the patience with me... My head was in quite a mess... Thank you very very much